# Kafka remove from Ubuntu

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Is it possible to remove Apache Kafka from Ubuntu 18.04 and reinstall? My problem is that I installed Source download from official site, caught exception "Classpath is empty. Please build the project first e.g. by running './gradlew jar -PscalaVersion=2.12.10'
" and after recommendation from this topic
[Classpath is empty. Please build the project first e.g. by running './gradlew jar -PscalaVersion=2.11.12'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50197965/classpath-is-empty-please-build-the-project-first-e-g-by-running-gradlew-ja/50325347)
I want to install from binaries files.

Comment: how did you install it previously?

Comment: I successfully installed zookeeper 3.4.6, then unpacked from 
http://kafka.apache.org/downloads.html
source download kafka-2.5.0-src.tgz,
then moved by this comands:
$ sudo tar -zxf kafka-2.5.0-src.tgz
$ sudo mv kafka-2.5.0-src /usr/local/kafka
 $ mkdir /tmp/kafka-logs
$ export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
$ /usr/local/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh -daemon
and then caught exception "Classpath is empty. Please build the project first e.g. by running './gradlew jar -PscalaVersion=2.12.10' "

Answer (score 2):

I made the same mistake of installing the source instead of the binary and got the same `Classpath is empty. Please build the project first e.g. by running './gradlew jar -PscalaVersion=2.13.2'` error.

I noticed that there was actually a `gradlew` executable in the directory that you installed `kafka`. Running `./gradlew jar -PscalaVersion=2.13.2` fixed the issue for me.